# Sending an email to all users with access rights to SharePoint online subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, nintex

I'd like to create a "Send an Email" workflow and assign the "To" section to all users who have access to the site. This doesn't appear to be an option in the "Workflow Context". Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround, you could add the users who can assess to the site into one group.

Then you could select the SharePoint group in the "Send an Email" in the workflow.